# Facing issue in debugging application on windows server 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

We have developed web application using MVC and deployed application on windows server 2019 standard edition.
I am trying to debug application and enabled remote debugger on server and it is running fine.
[image]

When I am trying to attach process I am not able to find machine,and it is showing as no results.There is no visual studio installed on server.I am using Visual studio 2017 on my local system.

[image]

Please let me know how can i attach process and debug the code deployed on Windows server for any issues.

Answer (score 0):

When ever I do remote debugging, I follow this:

1. Start remote debugger as an admin user
2. Open vs on my machine and hit debug->Attach to process
3. Leave connection type as Default
4. Enter the machines remote name in the Connection Target

That should do it, it has never been more complicated than that.  If you do get errors connecting, ensure your firewall is allowing the port

Comment: @Slickism - I am not sure what is issue in connecting with remote debugger.As per the image means debugger is up and running right?Please correct me If I am wrong or anything else need to enable on remote server.